# IONIC: loading listview from JSON array

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="starter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic List Directive</title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jsonCntrl.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCntrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Items List</h1>
     </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list >
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in myData">
          {{ item.Name }}
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
     </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my Controller Code :

```
angular.module('starter', []).controller('myCntrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response){
                    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
       }); 
});
```

I am not getting a list view instead something like this

[List response Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4vnw.png)

But when i use the same code to populate data from an array its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
angular.module('starter', []).controller('myCntrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http
        .get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = angular.fromJson(response.data.records);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code you have and check the styles of .item class in ionic.css file with the line of 5646 else override that class with below style

```
border-color: #ddd;
background-color: #fff;
color: #444;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
margin: -1px;
padding: 16px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
font-size: 16px;
```

Comment: when i change .then to .success its not even loading the JSON array, its showing an empty screen

Comment: i checked with the same API call and able to get the list as you like. Please check your controller once again